# Can't figure out how to call a method from a different class

Tags: c#

I'm taking a C# course and one of our assignments asks us to find the area and perimeter of a rectangle using multiple methods for each formula and to use user input for height and width. I've tried setting it up so I have one class with the area and perimeter formulas and one class that takes user input and creates an output. My issue is that I keep getting:

```
"error CS1501: No overload for method `area' takes `0' arguments"
```

for area and perimeter. How can I fix this?

I've tried using different call methods like:

```
FormulaMethods a = new FormulaMethods();
double area;
area = a.area();
```

as well as separate namespace as well as different call methods. Nothing has worked so far.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace RectangleCalculator
{
    public class FormulaMethods 
    {
        public static void area(double height, double width) 
        {
            double area = height * width;
        }
        public static void perimeter(double height, double width)
        {
            double perimeter = (2 * (height + width));
        }
    }
    public class Program 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Height of your rectangle: ");
            double height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Width of your rectangle: ");
            double width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("The Height of your rectangle is: " + height);
            Console.WriteLine("The Width of your rectangle is: " + width);
            
            FormulaMethods a = new FormulaMethods();
            double area;
            area = a.area();
            Console.WriteLine("The Area of your rectangle is: " + area);
            
            FormulaMethods p = new FormulaMethods();
            double perimeter;
            perimeter = p.perimeter();
            Console.WriteLine("The Perimeter of your rectangle is: " + perimeter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you've written your `area` function is you must pass the height and width to it, as the error says.  Your code isn't going to print anything because you're not returning or even saving anything from that function anyways.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of functions, you want to return the calculated value. `void` means this method doesn't return a value. You should change that to `double`.

The problem with you code is that `double area = height * width;` defines a variable, but doesn't return anything.

```
public class FormulaMethods 
{
    public static double area(double height, double width) 
    {
        // use the return statement to return the calculated value
        return height * width;
    }
    public static double perimeter(double height, double width)
    {
        // use the return statement to return the calculated value
        return (2 * (height + width));
    }
}
```

You program will look like this:

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Height of your rectangle: ");
        double height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Width of your rectangle: ");
        double width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("The Height of your rectangle is: " + height);
        Console.WriteLine("The Width of your rectangle is: " + width);
        
        // Since you created static methods, you don't need an instance of that class.
        // Just call the method directly on the class.
        double area = FormulaMethods.area(width, height);
        Console.WriteLine("The Area of your rectangle is: " + area);
        
        double perimeter = FormulaMethods.perimeter(width, height);
        Console.WriteLine("The Perimeter of your rectangle is: " + perimeter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've tried implementing your recommended changes and now I'm receiving the error "error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer."

Comment: Found it, it was a typo... `p.perimeter(width, height);` must be `FormulaMethods.perimeter(width, height);`   did you noticed why it should be changed? (or just copy/paste?)

Comment: I did notice that and changed it prior to replying, I got that error after. I noticed that it needed to call from the FormulaMethods class instead of the leftover p from my own attempt at calling